# Flink-elasticsearch artifact id is missing?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink

I am using flink v1.3.0 and elasticsearch version v5.x but for this there is no maven dependency available in maven central . Max it is available for flink v1.2.1 with elasticsearch v2 .can some tell me where can i find this connector jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem when releasing the artifacts related to the required java version, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6812.